# Django: Create Additional ModelAdmin pages loaded by admin action

Tags: django, django-admin

I've found docs indicating how to edit ModelAdmin but I need a new one that I can load from an action as follows:

I have a model called campaigns
I have a model called ads

I can view ads of course from the admin and it will give me a complete, paginated list of all ads. I would like to be able to create an action on the campaigns admin view that will load the ads admin view but with a campaign id so that I may see only ads for the specific campaign.

I could create a custom view and call it as an action from the admin, but of course this would be a lot of work. I'd like for the ads listing to look just like the standard admin view for ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is the ability to filter ads by campaign, you don't need to create a special admin / action for this, all it requires is properly configuring your ads admin's [`list_filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter), ie (assuming `Ads` has a `ForeignKey` on `Campaign`):

```
class AdsAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_filter = ["campaign", ]
```

If you want to use some `Campaign`'s specific field for display in the filters sidebar (here we assume `Campaign` as a `name` field):

```
class AdsAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_filter = ["campaign__name", ]
```

Also note that you can manage a campaign's ads on the `Campaign`'s change form too using [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) which is usually a better UI for master/slave relationships (and it doesn't prevent you to keep the `Ads` admin for a global - and filterable - overview).